# Replace a FASTA sequence according to its id with gaps

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have 2000 fasta sequence in a file, like this:

```
 >T1        
AQSFDRATVFEARRAGYQRESRVALGKSTGVLEWHVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQIECSGKGIADRRQENPLTI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDIVIMDFKAITQFFL     
>T484      
AQSFDRATVFEARRAGYQREARVALGKSTGKLEWQVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQLECSGKGIADRRQENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDIVIMDFKAITQFFL     
>T582      
AQSFDRATVFEKRRAGYQREARVALGKSTGKLEWQVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQLECSGKGIADRRQENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDIVIMDFKAITQFFL     
>T1424     
AQSFDRATVFEKRRAGYQLEARVALGKSTGKLEWQVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQLECSGKGIANRRQENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDILIMDFKAITQFFL     
>T1552     
AQSFDRATIFEKRRAGYQIEARVALGKSTGKLEWQVYHAWAPRETTILVETLSQLENAGKGVANRRHENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDILMMDFKAITQFFL     
.
.
.
```

I wish to randomly draw f sequence from N (N = 2000 sequences).

For example if f=2, I randomly draw 2 sequences from 2000 sequences.

```
f=2 

l=[] 

for i in range(f):
    x=randint(1, N)
    l.append(x)
```

In my list l, I would have for example [291, 566]. Then, I want to draw the 291th and 566th sequences:

```
> T1424
AQSFDRATVFEKRRAGYQLEARVALGKSTGKLEWQVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQLECSGKGIANRRQENPLKI ------ ATAI - TSQLLELVDILIMDFKAITQFFL
> T1552
AQSFDRATIFEKRRAGYQIEARVALGKSTGKLEWQVYHAWAPRETTILVETLSQLENAGKGVANRRHENPLKI ------ ATAI - TSQLLELVDILMMDFKAITQFFL
```

What I want to do is replace these sequences with gaps ("-") of length 55:

```
> T1424
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> T1552
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried with this code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO 
from random import *

records = list(SeqIO.parse("fichier1.txt", "fasta")) 
#print(records[0].id)  # first record
#print(records[0].seq)

N=len(records) #2000 

f=2 

l=[] 

for i in range(f):
    x=randint(1, N)
    l.append(x)

d={} 
for i2 in l:
    print(records[i2].id,records[i2].seq)
    d[str(records[i2].id)]=str(records[i2].seq)
    with open("fichier1.txt") as fichier, open("newfile.txt", "w") as newfile:
        texte = fichier.read()

        new_text += texte.replace(str(records[i2].seq), "---------------------------------------")
        newfile.write(new_text)

print(d)
```

What does not work because sometimes there can be the same sequence in the file but with a different identifier.

From the ID and the corresponding sequence, I would like to change the sequence to introduce gaps.

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting. Can you provide a walk through using a single example?

Comment: @Alex I want to replace sequences that I drew randomly by gaps of length 55.

Comment: You want to replace the entire sequence with `-` * 55?

Comment: Yes exactly and replace the old file with a new one with these modifications

Comment: i could write a solution, but *why* do you want to do this? what is your bioinformatic/scientific use case? it seems like an odd thing to do

Comment: @Chris_Rands This is to simulate the fact that certain ribosomal proteins are absent for certain organisms

Answer (score 2):

I can solve your coding problem (although I'm still not convinced this it the best way to handle your scientific issue- i.e. absence of certain ribsomal proteins). Anyway, here is a solution, rather than rely on the sequences being unique, I simply tracked the indexes of the sequences:

```
import random

from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

num_to_sample = 2

# WARNING: puts all sequences in memory
lst = list(SeqIO.parse("fichier1.txt", "fasta"))

sample = set(random.sample(range(len(lst)), num_to_sample))

for idx, record in enumerate(lst):
    if idx in sample:
        record.seq = Seq(len(record.seq) * "-")
    print(record.format("fasta"), end='')
```

Example output:

```
>T1
AQSFDRATVFEARRAGYQRESRVALGKSTGVLEWHVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQIECSGK
GIADRRQENPLTI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDIVIMDFKAITQFFL
>T484
AQSFDRATVFEARRAGYQREARVALGKSTGKLEWQVFHVWAPRETTILVETLSQLECSGK
GIADRRQENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDIVIMDFKAITQFFL
>T582
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
>T1424
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
>T1552
AQSFDRATIFEKRRAGYQIEARVALGKSTGKLEWQVYHAWAPRETTILVETLSQLENAGK
GVANRRHENPLKI------ATAI--TSQLLELVDILMMDFKAITQFFL
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is really great, that's exactly what I wanted !!

Comment: @Citho Consider marking this question as correct if it helped you.